# How is k-means implemented in CNN?

Tags: k-means, yolo

I am new to CNN and want to try implementing YOLOv4 with a custom dataset for vehicles. As I understand it, k-means clustering is done to give labels to a set of data. I was going through some papers like [Article 1](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3628439) and I am confused by why they are using k-means clustering when they are using a public dataset that has already been labeled.

Comment: They aren't using K-Means to label the data. The abstract is very clear: "The aim of this paper is to improve the newly released, YOLOv4 detector, specifically, for vehicle tracking applications using some existing methods such as optimising anchor box predictions by using k-means clustering."